# User Authentication failed while logging through Gmail and Facebook

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am unable to login into my app through Gmail and Facebook because it says authentication failed while I have entered login details. I have integrated Gmail and Facebook login and there is no error on that. It shows the initial page and while I connect to my account to login then it shows an authentication failed message.

Comment: Have you added needed keys and registered your project on gmail and facebook developer's console?

Comment: Hii Priyanka I am an intermediate android learner please give me suggestions and how can I learn efficiently if possible please help me 
https://www.instagram.com/ankur_lakhmara/

Comment: Also, take care of running in debug and release mode. because it may cause the same error